# `AudioContext().audioWorklet.addModule()`, how to load by `Blob`?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-worker, audiocontext

I am trying to use `new AudioContext(). audioWorklet.addModule(URL.createObjectURL(blob))`Load, but the console prompts error: cross source, if it is `file://` protocol, how to use `audioWorklet`?

I tried to use `new Blob([Source Code], {type: 'application/javascript'});`, but still prompted an error

> However, the `file://`protocol `new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))` method can be used in Chrome.

```
const getMp3=()=>{
    // return arrayBuffer
};

const playWorkletStr = async () => {
    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    let audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(getMp3());

    let bypass = `class Bypass extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
                    process(inputs, outputs) {
                        const input = inputs[0];
                        const output = outputs[0];

                        for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {
                            output[channel].set(input[channel]);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                registerProcessor('bypass', Bypass);
                `;
    let blob = new Blob([bypass], {type: 'application/javascript'});

    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    const bypasser = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'bypass');

    let source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(bypasser).connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.start();
};
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = () => {
    playWorkletStr();
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">play</button>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem in Chrome, while Firefox didn't seem to block blob URI here. I've found a solution or workaround to this problem: simply using `FileReader.readAsDataURL(blob)` instead of `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` seems to work.

I found this workaround when I was trying `audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule("file:///path_to_js")`, Chrome showed an error message in console:

> Access to script at 'file:///path_to_js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.

I saw `data` listed here so I tried it, then it seemed to work.

However, I'm not sure whether this is allowed in principle.

```
    let blob = new Blob([bypass], {type: 'application/javascript'});

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    let dataURI = await new Promise((res) => {
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            res(reader.result);
        }
    });
    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule(dataURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

`file://`  protocol is considered cross-origin in Chrome. This means that blob URIs will also be considered cross-origin from this protocol, and your worklet will refuse to compile from cross-origin scripts.

To avoid that, the best is to start a local server on your machine. If you are going to do web-development, that's a must, and takes only a few minutes to set up depending on your OS.

Now if you really wish to use the `file://` protocol, then you can try to start your chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

Comment: However, the `file://`protocol" `new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))` method can be used in Chrome.